# Mapping using 3d model of an arena

Tags: mapping

so I am participating in a rover making competition where they have given us a parasolid file of the arena. Our rover is primarily going use the raspberry pi as the brain with most likely ROS as its OS and some arduino boards to control the movement of motors and a robotic arm.

I am working on the software side of the team and I wonder if there is a way to use a 3d model of an arena and use that to map the entire arena for the rover, since in that arena the rover has to move through a pre determined coordinates so as to test its mechanical aspect.

So yea the tldr for the question is: Is there a way to use a 3d model of an arena (parasolid file) to map the arena and let the rover know in what coordinate what is present.

Comment: Good question - did you figure it out?

Comment: @WINk nope, i tried to look for something but there isnt anything like that. There is no other way than to do SLAM. Plus our report was submitted to the judges on how we are going to build the rover but unfortunately it was rejected so we werent funded on the project :(